# AlarmManager RTC_WAKEUP drains battery

Tags: android, android-service, alarmmanager

I have a service running in the background which periodically downloads data from the server. I need to download the data after every one hour. But the battery is draining fast. The code is as below. How do I make the alarm power efficient?

```
public class BackgroundFetchService extends Service {

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        int s = super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

        BackgroundFetchManager.getSharedInstance().setAlarmStatus(false);

        TherapyManager.getSharedInstance().downloadData(new DataManager.DataManagerListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(AppError error) {
                stopSelf();
            }
        });

        return s;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        //restart this service again in one hour

        if(!BackgroundFetchManager.getSharedInstance().getAlarmStatus()) {
            AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarm.set(
                    alarm.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    System.currentTimeMillis() + (1000 * 60 * 60),
                    PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, new Intent(this, BackgroundFetchService.class), 0)
            );
            BackgroundFetchManager.getSharedInstance().setAlarmStatus(true);
        }

        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you even know it's the alarm's fault that the battery is "drained"?

Answer (score 0):

Try with only **RTC**, because according to the document : https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html,  **RTC** Fires the pending intent at the specified time but does not wake up the device.

For example:

```
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarm.set(
        alarm.RTC,
        System.currentTimeMillis() + (1000 * 60 * 60),
        PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, new Intent(this, BackgroundFetchService.class), 0)
);
BackgroundFetchManager.getSharedInstance().setAlarmStatus(true);
```